# How to run SQL server agent jobs with different AD accounts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our SQL server agent already setup an AD account (e.g. MyCompany\Bob) for scheduled jobs. The logon setup is done via service.msc.

Recently, we have a new T-SQL job that connects to another SQL Server instance via linked server. Another AD account (MyCompany\Alice) is required for connection.

Is it possible to setup like that? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You create the AD account as a SQL Server _credential_, then you create a SQL Server Agent _proxy_ that uses the credential.

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy. Then when you create your job, the proxy will be available in the drop down